# filter is not working fine in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am working with google sheet and this worked fine, but today i wanted do a filter and this is not filter all the sheet... only  first 444 rows... i see this has a square  and this is filter only rows inside square, but how was it added and how can i remove it?

I add the images now..
i do the filter here

[image]

after you could see the filter is fine (in the square after it, this is not filtering)

[image]

and this is the table with not filter

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the images your filter is defined only for a specific range, which is up to row 444. This was done when `Data -> Create Filter` menu option was used when a range is already selected.

You can delete this filter by selecting `Data -> Turn off Filter`, then recreating another for the whole sheet by selecting the first cell in the whole sheet, then selecting `Data -> Create Filter` again.

**Before creating filter, range selected:**

[image]

**After creating filter, range selected:**

[image]

**Before creating filter, single cell selected:**

[image]

**After creating filter, single cell selected:**

[image]